# How to insert variable number of values into a table in SQLite using prepared statement

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, prepared-statement

The table X has three columns(a,b,c) in which one column has a default value of 0. Sometimes I get values for the other two columns only. And sometimes I get the values for all the three columns. `INSERT INTO X (a,b) VALUES (?,?)` or `INSERT INTO X (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)`. Is there any way to make it a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the three column insert query and simply bind `None` as the `c` parameter when you only want to specify values for `a` and `b`:

```py
params = (a, b, None,)
db.execute('INSERT INTO X (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)', params)
```

To be explicit, the following two inserts should have identical behavior:

```sql
INSERT INTO X (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, NULL);
INSERT INTO X (a, b) VALUES (?, ?);
```

assuming we bind the same values to the first two `?` placeholders in each of the above queries.